# windows 8.1 embedded industry with no WI-FI

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, embedded

I just installed windows 8.1 embedded industry on my Transcend storejet M3  and its working perfectly. But here comes the big issue no WiFi  in the connection settings is just proxy and VPN in wireless devices is Bluetooth and the human device interface flight mode help me Discover WIFI

Comment: The Transcend is a hard drive. A hard drive doesn't run an operating system. A computer does. You made no mention of what computer this is. Drivers for wireless are downloaded from the computer manufacturer's website.

Comment: The computer is dell inspiron 14-3552  running windows 10 pro. I  downloaded the drivers especially the network card from dell website for windows 8.1  but during installation they're unable to get installed. I fail to understand what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding a Dell 14 3552, but I did find a 15 3552. If we are talking about the same system, there are several different network adapter drivers listed. The laptop could have any of a number of different hardware versions. It's a matter of getting the right one. Make sure you look up your drivers by service tag.

If you are having trouble identifying which driver version you need you can look at the hardware ID of the device in device manager.  Find the problematic hardawre in device manager, right-click and choose `properties` then click the `details` tab. Change your `property` to `Hardware IDs`. Copy and paste one of the IDs in to google and you should see pretty quickly what hardware you are using. Then go back to the Dell site and download the proper driver for that specific type of hardware.

Or, you might need a little trial and error. But, one thing for certain is that there isn't just one choice under Network Drivers on the Dell website.